# React hooks - manage API call every minute

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to make API GET request every minute and render the data from the API.
I saw already that this question asked before and there is a good answer as well here:

[React hooks to manage API call with a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903703/react-hooks-to-manage-api-call-with-a-timer?answertab=votes#tab-top)

My question is, that approach is re-render the component every second/millisecond right?
If so, there is a better way to do it without re-render the component every second and only re-render the component every minute with the API call?

Comment: use `setInterval` with specific milliseconds for one min, so it will do the trigger on minutes bases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it can see a little bit obvious and if you can , but I would change the `tick()` to be  and `setInterval` timing `60000`.

You can find this approach here in this Sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-endpoint-timer-2fwxx?file=/src/App.js

If you want to avoid re-render the component every time, you need to drop the timer `count` to be showed in the viewport.